AssignedRenderMode in Blazor layout not available?
I have a MainLayout in Blazor that will sometimes run in Static Server Rendering on the server, but mostly runs in Interactive Webassembly.
I don't want things that don't work in static mode displayed so I tried to use 'AssignedRenderMode' to identify the mode and exclude parts of the render as follows:


@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@implements IDisposable
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


@using System.Globalization
@using RaffleGames.Client.Components
<Layout>
    <LayoutHeader Background="Background.Dark">
        <div class="header">
            @if (LoggedIn() && AssignedRenderMode != null)
            { 
              ... stuff to exclude here
            }
            



What you can't see there is the underlined 'red squiggle' that Visual Studio puts up when it can't figure something out. But the image from a build errors shows:
|
Microsoft seems to think it should be ok? So I am confused. I am not sure if I have missed adding something to the project or have just missed something else.
AssignedRenderMode is part of ComponentBase, but LayoutComponentBase inherits that and also has it.
Any ideas?

You must have other problems in the page or your application.  This works [I've just tested in in Net9 AutoRenderMode and Per Page Interactivity], so you need to provide a [MRE] to demonstrate the problem.

Ok, thanks. Without that it build loads and runs just fine, which is why I am confused. It could be a visual studio restart is needed or something. I'll give that a go. Cheers.

Clear the obj and bin folders.

Ok.. Thanks will try it... theres been some other wierdness going on now as well with the default culture server side being US and on the client (same component) coming in with en-gb - which is what it is supposed to be... cheers..
